# Fortran's findloc with character type

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm confused by the `findloc` intrinsic with a character array.
The program

```
print *, findloc(['AB'],'A',dim=1)
end
```

outputs

```
           1
```

while I expected `0`.

I thought that `findloc` searched for equality, and `'A' /= 'AB'`.
If I make the scalar value of equal type as the array, then I do get what I expected: `findloc(['AB'],'A ',dim=1)` gives `0`.

Note that `findloc(['BA'],'A',dim=1)` does give `0`, so I don't think that `findloc` uses the `index` function.

I'm using `ifort 18.0.3` on `centos 7`.

Comment: Yes, I used `ifort -O0 -stand f08 -warn all -check all`. And `findloc` is Fortran 2008, so I'd be surprised if their implementation is old. Besides, I thought that this behavior would be standardized.

Comment: Can you try with 19.0.1?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. And my version of `gfortran` is way too old.

Comment: Its just a compiler bug.  You can report such things at http://supporttickets.intel.com/.

Comment: @francescalus I tested this with Intel Fortran Compiler 2019, and the bug persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this is a bug in Intel Fortran's findloc() implementation.  I created an Intel bug report to our developers.

Comment: So it's possible to write a 28-byte full program that triggers a bug: `print*,findloc(['A'],'');end`. That must be some sort of record.


But these things happen, and Fortran's characters are probably not the easiest to deal with. Thank you for letting us know.